# blazorstrap InputType.select not binding

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazorstrap

trying to create a very basic form with blazorstrap.

```
@page "/testform"

<h1> test form @Status</h1>
<EditForm Model=@Person OnSubmit=@FormSubmitted>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <p>
        <label>
            name:
            <BSBasicInput T="string"
                          InputType="InputType.Text"
                          @bind-value=Person.Name />
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>
            Age:
            <InputNumber @bind-Value="Person.Age" />
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>
            type:
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="Person.Type">
                <option value="">Select classification ...</option>
                @foreach (var enumType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(BankAccountType)))
                {
                    <option value="@enumType">@enumType</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
            @* <BSBasicInput T="BankAccountType?" InputType="InputType.Select" @bind-Value="Person.Type"> *@
            @*     <option value="">Select classification ...</option> *@
            @*     @foreach (var enumType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(BankAccountType))) *@
            @*     { *@
            @*         <option value="@enumType">@enumType</option> *@
            @*     } *@
            @* </BSBasicInput> *@
</label>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</EditForm>
@code
{
    string Status = "Not submitted";
    Person Person = new Person();
    BankAccountType? AccountType = null;

    void FormSubmitted()
    {
        Status = "Form submitted";
        Console.WriteLine($"person: {Person} + " + AccountType);
    }

    private void SelectedChanged(BankAccountType? value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("changed " + value);
    }
}
```

the person class is

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public BankAccountType? Type { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            var accountType = Type.HasValue ? Type.Value.ToString() : "";
            return $"{Name} is {Age} years old {accountType}";
        }
    }
```

The name binding with BSBasicInput works fine. using InputSelect for the select works fine. but when I try and use BSBasicInput with the InputType.Select (see commented out part).  I cannot get it to bind, or at least show it is ever changing or setting either Person.Type or when I directly create a property in the razor file for it.

Sure I must be doing something wrong here, and its not blazorstrap, but can't see what it is now

Answer (score 2):

```
<BSBasicInput T="BankAccountType" InputType="InputType.Select" @bind-Value="Person.Type">
                <option value="">Select classification ...</option>
                @foreach (var enumType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(BankAccountType)))
                {
                    <option value="@enumType">@enumType</option>
                }
            </BSBasicInput>
```

This works.  It seems to be that `BSBasicInput` cannot handle nullable enums